# Move a ball on Grid path randomly in Canvas Android

Tags: android, android-canvas

Requirement is to keep a ball moving on the Grid path generated in Canvas. I have generated a Grid in canvas but not able to understand how to move the ball randomly means starting point show be different on the path. I am sharing what I have done. I have also plotted the ball in the screen but not getting the point how to put the ball exactly on the grid line randomly and start moving it

```
public class PixelGridView extends View {

    //number of row and column
    int horizontalGridCount = 11;

    private Drawable horiz;
    private Drawable vert;
    private final float width;
    long mInterpolateTime;
    PointF mImageSource = new PointF();


    public PixelGridView(@NonNull Context context) {
        this(context, null);
    }

    public PixelGridView(@NonNull Context context, @Nullable AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        horiz = new ColorDrawable(Color.WHITE);
        horiz.setAlpha(160);
        vert = new ColorDrawable(Color.WHITE);
        vert.setAlpha(160);
        width = TypedValue.applyDimension(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, .9f, context.getResources().getDisplayMetrics());
    }

    @Override
    protected void onLayout(boolean changed, int left, int top, int right, int bottom) {
        super.onLayout(changed, left, top, right, bottom);
        horiz.setBounds(left, 0, right, (int) width);
        vert.setBounds(0, top, (int) width, bottom);
    }


    private float getLinePosition(int lineNumber) {
        int lineCount = horizontalGridCount;
        return (1f / (lineCount + 1)) * (lineNumber + 1f);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        super.onDraw(canvas);
        //drawTask.start();
        Paint paint = new Paint();
        paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL);
        paint.setColor(Color.WHITE);
        paint.setAntiAlias(true);
        canvas.drawCircle(120, 110, 10, paint);

        int count = horizontalGridCount;

        for (int n = 0; n < count; n++) {
            float pos = getLinePosition(n);
            // Draw horizontal line
            canvas.translate(0, pos * getHeight());
            Log.e("Position1", "" + pos * getHeight());
            horiz.draw(canvas);
            canvas.translate(0, -pos * getHeight());
            // Draw vertical line
            canvas.translate(pos * getHeight(), 0);
            Log.e("Position2", "" + pos * getHeight());
            vert.draw(canvas);
            canvas.translate(-pos * getHeight(), 0);
        }
    }
}[![Canvas Image][1]][1]

//MainActivity
public class PathAnimationActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    LinearLayout rlLayout;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_path);
        rlLayout=findViewById(R.id.rlLayout);

        PixelGridView pixelGrid = new PixelGridView(this);
        rlLayout.addView(pixelGrid);

    }

}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

First thing i have noticed it that you haven't used invalidate (); at the end because thats critical in order to animate the canvas ( redraw the frames ) so please include that .

there may be several ways to achieve what you want follows is my idea
this canvas need to be divided into multiple x , y divided planes as follows and save them in array  of points which you can randomize and give those points to ball to move ,

Step 1, get the canvas size
step 2, divide is in x and y coordinate depending on size of each device varies so you need to control that factor via Screen size
step 3, save the coordinates in matrix or array
step 4, set position of balls from those arrays values ( randomly can you define the random limits as per the max and min values of x and y from the coordinates division .

example , function move will take ball object and x, y are the positions  move (ball, x, y ); and you can randomize the x and y based on max and min limits of your coordinates division example total y lines and total x lines values

in order to get an idea about how to move the ball on canvas you can see this code here : https://github.com/pintspin/ball_animation

[image]